# Как добавить option из одного селекта в другой?

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select id="select1" class="form-control" size="4" name="fruct[]" multiple>
        <option value="1">яблоко</option>
        <option value="2">апельсин</option>
        <option value="3">виноград</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <select id="select2" class="form-control" size="4" name="fruct[]" multiple>
        <option value="1">арбуз</option>
        <option value="2">дыня</option>
        <option value="3">помидор</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <h6>Добавить:</h6>

    <button id="js-button-2" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary">В конец</button>

</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://snipp.ru/cdn/bootstrap/4.3/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://snipp.ru/cdn/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.btn-default').click(function(){
        $('#select option:contains("новый option")').remove();
    });



    // Добавить элемент в конец select
    $('#js-button-2').click(function(){
        $('#select1').append('<option value="" style="color:green;">новый option</option>');
    });


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.btn-default').click(function() {
  $('#select option:contains("новый option")').remove();
});



// Добавить элемент в конец select
$('#js-button-2').click(function() {
  if ($('#select2 :selected').length) //добавлять только, если что-то выбрано.
    $('#select1').append(`<option value="" style="color:green;">${$('#select2 :selected').text()}</option>`);
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <select id="select1" class="form-control" size="4" name="fruct[]" multiple>
    <option value="1">яблоко</option>
    <option value="2">апельсин</option>
    <option value="3">виноград</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <select id="select2" class="form-control" size="4" name="fruct[]" multiple>
    <option value="1">арбуз</option>
    <option value="2">дыня</option>
    <option value="3">помидор</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <h6>Добавить:</h6>

  <button id="js-button-2" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary">В конец</button>

</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://snipp.ru/cdn/bootstrap/4.3/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://snipp.ru/cdn/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```